# Delete zero values and plot the distribution - Python (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have this grouped data, which is the average of listings per host.

```
host_id
310835509    892.0
121985032    581.0
1464510      100.0
517215        88.0
65859990      85.0
             ...  
138762026      0.0
138739439      0.0
4741854        0.0
4760591        0.0
75550005       0.0
```

I want to drop the zero values and plot the distribution of this.I tried various methods but I am getting wrong outputs.

Comment: What means `plot the distribution of this.` ?

Comment: histogram probably?

Comment: Yes i meant histogram.

Answer (score 2):

For remove `0` in `Series` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = s[s != 0]
```

If need counts values in histogram:

```
out.plot.hist()
```

Or counts in bar plot:

```
out.value_counts.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.randint(0, 5, 1000)

y = [numb for numb in y if numb != 0]

plt.hist(y)
plt.show()
```

in your case I would just do the same as I did with y and iterate over the array/list to find all values that are not 0 and keep them in your list.

EDIT: Sorry didn't notice you said Pandas.

As previously mentioned you can do the following:

```
df = df[df['your_column']!=0]
```

You can utilise Pandas, example from documentation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 7, 6000), columns = ['one'])
df['two'] = df['one'] + np.random.randint(1, 7, 6000)
ax = df.plot.hist(bins=12, alpha=0.5)
```

Or you could use maptlotlib, previous example might be sufficient.